# Matrices invariant under conjugation by matrix group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of real $n\times n$ matrices. I'd like to find the set of real $n\times n$ matrices $A$ such that for all $P\in G$ we have
$$P^{-1}AP = A.$$
I suspect that all these matrices $A$ are of the form $A = \sum_{P\in G} P^{-1}WP$ for some $W$.

My question is:

#### Is this true? Where do I find theory about this?

I would also be interested in some worked out examples in the literature.

Comment: The set of such matrices $A\in G$ is the center $Z(G)$. What is the sum $\sum_{P\in G}$ in case $G$ is infinite?

Comment: Ah, then consider finite groups. Note that A need not to be in G but can be any n by n matrix. I clarify the question.

Comment: This is the endomorphism algebra of $G$.

Comment: Start by considering the trivial group. Could you disprove your conjecture in this case?

Comment: No I can't, because it is true. (If is only the identity, then the sun gives W for every W and every W commutes with the identity.)

Comment: @derekholt Sounds interesting - could you give pointers? (Wikipedia is not really helpful (only has endomorphism rings associated with abelian groups).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. Let ${\rm End}(G)$ (the endomorphism ring of $G$) be the set of matrices $A$ with $P^{-1}AP=A$ for all $P \in G$.

It is easy to check that $\sum_{P \in G} P^{-1}WP$ lies in ${\rm End}(G)$ for any matrix $W$.

Conversely, if $A \in {\rm End}(G)$, then just put $W = A/|G|$ and we get $\sum_{P \in G} P^{-1}WP = A$.

Like many results in the representation theory of finite groups, this proof works in any field of characteristic $0$ or in charatceristic $p$ not dividing $|G|$.